# Floor function inequality, for which x<y real is $\lfloor x \rfloor < \lfloor y \rfloor$?

Tags: calculus, inequality, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Floor function inequality, for which $x<y$ real is $\lfloor x\rfloor < \lfloor y\rfloor$ ?

Maybe I'm not thinking about this correctly but would x have to negative and y positive?

Comment: Let $x=4.5$ and $y=5.5$. Then $x<y$ and $\lfloor x \rfloor < \lfloor y \rfloor$.

Comment: well, just use '$\leq$', especially $\lfloor x\rfloor\leq\lfloor y\rfloor$

Answer (score 1):

$0 < .5$ but $0=\lfloor 0\rfloor \not < \lfloor .5 \rfloor = 0$

So in general we need that their integer part is not the same (the part before the decimal)

Put another way, we say that $x< y$ if and only if $y-x>0$ (this works for positive and negative numbers and integers).

Comment: the integer part has to be less than?

Comment: YES!    Because the floor function just "ignores" the decimal part.  
Also it's important to realize this fact  $\lfloor x \rfloor - \lfloor y \rfloor \neq \lfloor x-y \rfloor$
For example, $\lfloor 4.5 \rfloor - \lfloor .6 \rfloor = 4-0=4$ but $\lfloor 4.5 - .6 \rfloor = \lfloor 3.9 \rfloor = 3$

Comment: No, you don't need "the integer part has to be less than", see my answer below.

Comment: Sorry, I tihnk your answer was based on the problem statement, which I think should be "if $x<y$ then $\lfloor x \rfloor\leq \lfloor y \rfloor$ (rather than  $\lfloor x \rfloor< \lfloor y \rfloor$)

Answer (score 1):

Let $\epsilon_x,\epsilon_y\in R$, and $0\leq\epsilon_x,\epsilon_y<1$, and also $a_x,a_y\in Z$ ($a_x,a_x$ are integer valued: positive, negative or zero), then:

Define: $x=a_x+\epsilon_x$, and $y=a_y+\epsilon_y$, by definition of the floor function we have: $\lfloor x \rfloor=a_x$ and $\lfloor y \rfloor=a_y$,

Now if $x<y$, then $a_x+\epsilon_x<a_y+\epsilon_y$, now we prove $\lfloor x\rfloor \leq \lfloor y\rfloor$, by contradiction:

let's assume: $\lfloor x\rfloor > \lfloor y\rfloor$, then equivalently $a_x>a_y$ (while based on the problem statement: $a_x+\epsilon_x<a_y+\epsilon_y$).

$a_x>a_y$ implies $a_x-a_y\geq 1$ (*) (because $a_x$ and $a_y$ are integers.), therefore:

$a_x+\epsilon_x<a_y+\epsilon_y$

$\Rightarrow a_x-a_y<\epsilon_y-\epsilon_x$

$\Rightarrow 1\leq a_x-a_y<\epsilon_y-\epsilon_x$

$\Rightarrow \epsilon_y-\epsilon_x\geq 1$, which is a contradiction, because  $0\leq\epsilon_x,\epsilon_y<1$ and their difference can not be greater than or equal to $1$.

Therefore if $x<y$ then $a_x=\lfloor x \rfloor\leq \lfloor y \rfloor=a_y$

Comment: You have made the question easier by assuming $\leq$ when the OP stated $<$.

Comment: Yes I see, but then the answer is if $x<y$ then it doesn't necessarily satisfy $\lfloor x \rfloor< \lfloor y \rfloor)$, as discussed above as well. I thought it's a typo :)

Comment: The point on the OP appears to be to find the conditions needed so that $x<y$ gives $\lfloor x \rfloor < \lfloor y \rfloor$ or describe the set of $x<y$ that have $\lfloor x \rfloor < \lfloor y \rfloor$.